# Passing a string to an action?

Tags: smart-contract, action

I have an action that needs to operate on a string:

```
void token::MyAction(std::string key);
```

so I would expect I can make the call like this:

```
cleos push action MyAccount MyAction '["burn"]' -p MyAccount@active
```

but when I make the call, I get an error:

> Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
>   Error Details: assertion failure with message: read pending console
>   output:

**how can I pass a string to an action?**

for what it's worth, I also tried:

```
cleos push action MyAccount MyAction '{"key":"burn"}' -p MyAccount@active
```

which also failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is perfectly possible to pass strings to an action and the way the code had been structured was perfectly fine

the real problem turned out to be that I had redefined the `struct` behind the eosio::table and that caused the error.  not very intuitive at all

what I had to do was wipe out my whole network and recreate that table.  now it works

Answer (score 2):

yeah, this happens if you change the structure of your table without erasing the previous content see https://github.com/clockknock/eos-contract-example/tree/master/02-erase-table