# On method call: "assertion failure with message: read"

Tags: eosjs, eosiocpp

I am calling a method that is completely commented out. I am calling it from EOStudio and from command line tools. Is this a bug or does someone know how to fix this?

```
assertion failure with message: read
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Service Error",
  "error": {
    "code": 3050003,
    "name": "eosio_assert_message_exception",
    "what": "eosio_assert_message assertion failure",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "assertion failure with message: read",
        "file": "wasm_interface.cpp",
        "line_number": 924,
        "method": "eosio_assert"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the ABI file to make sure that the arguments match what the action is expecting. This error is usually caused by some kind of mismatch between the ABI file and the on-chain data.

Examples of when you get this are:

1. Passing incorrect argument list to an action when calling inline (for example, [passing a char* instead of a string](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/passing-a-string-to-an-action))
2. Creating table entries, and then changing the fields in a table without first deleting all the table entries (see [Table Migration](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/481/best-practice-to-handle-table-migrations))
3. Updating your code without also updating your ABI file.

If you update your question to show the example action and the command you are calling to execute the action, then I will edit my answer to give a more specific solution.

Comment: it was either (2) or a slightly different thing. i created a table but didn't set the index variable.

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: yes, but i'm just testing. i deployed to a different account. alternatively i could have re-created the table row with `emplace()` in the contract deployment with a maintenance method

Comment: Ok. Well if my answer satisfies you, you can accept it so that others can also learn from this